# History of Ephemeral NAT IP Addresses

Tags: google-compute-engine

Does anyone know if there is a way to find out the past ephemeral NAT IP addresses that a Google Compute Instance has used over the course of its lifetime/reboots?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is an existing solution that would show ytou historical data, but you could create your own log using the gcloud command line tool to write to cloud logging.

Note that this is using a beta command, so may change in the future.

First, ensure that the logging beta commands are installed by typing:

```
gcloud beta logging
```

If it does not work, you can install with:

```
sudo gcloud components install beta
```

On your instance setup a cron job to run some script according to a schedule:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Go to the bottom of the file and enter:

```
@reboot gcloud beta logging write ip_addr $(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
```

This will run the command **gcloud beta logging write ip_addr $(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")** after each reboot. This will write the current external IP address to the ip_addr log.

Depending on your setup, you may be better to put the gcloud command in a separate script and reference that in the crontab config.

Next go to [Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) and from the first drop down choose **Global** and from the second choose **ip_addr**.

Comment: Than you very much, as an FYI, I submitted a feature request which Google has accepted. No ETA but thanks again for that clever solution.